# Truncate text to be less than 280 characters and then each word excluding "," to be less than 20 characters

Tags: javascript, html, truncate

This is my js for changing

```
#tag1 #tag2 #thisisareallyreallyrealyylongtag3
```

into

```
tag1, tag2, thisisareallyreallyrealyylongtag3
```

and it also Truncates the result down to 13 words..

```
  var str9 = document.getElementById("hashtagsplain").innerHTML;
  var resu9 = str9.replace(/^#|( #)/g, (_, m1) => m1 ? ", " : '');  
  var truncatethen = resu9.split(" ").splice(0,13).join(" ").slice(0, -1);
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = truncatethen;
```

What I now need to add into that is to truncate the text as a whole to be less than 280 characters and then truncate the end of each word (tag) excluding "," to be less than 20 characters.

What do I add and to where for this to happen please?

**UPDATE..**

I've sussed out the 280 char limit part by adding

```
(/^(.{280}[^\s]*).*/, "$1")
```

Now my code looks like this..

```
  var str9 = document.getElementById("hashtagsplain").innerHTML;
  var resu9 = str9.replace(/^#|( #)/g, (_, m1) => m1 ? ", " : '');  
  var resu10 = resu9.replace(/^(.{280}[^\s]*).*/, "$1");    
  var truncatethen = resu10.split(" ").splice(0,13).join(" ").slice(0, -1);
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = truncatethen;
```

I just now need to work out how to truncate each word excluding "," to be less than 20 characters so

```
notalldisabilitiesarevisible, notalldisabilitiesarevisable, notalldisabilities
```

becomes

```
notalldisabilitiesar, notalldisabilitiesar, notalldisabilities
```

Comment: What do you expect the final output to be?

Comment: What will be the order? First remove the #, trim to 280 chars and then trim each tag to 20?

Comment: Thinking about the final output it will be a comma-separated list, 
and for the order..

It should 1st remove the hashtags and replace with commas (as my posted code does) then it should truncate the result down to 13 words as it does) next it should trim the whole thing to 280 chars and then finally it should trim the end off each tag (not including, so keeping the comma) so that each tag is under 20 chars.

Comment: I've updated my op as I've been able to work out the 280 char limit part so I just now need to work out how to truncate each word excluding "," to be less than 20 characters. Examples of input and expected output now in updated op.

Answer (score 0):

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) could simplify the process

```js
var str9 = '#tag1 #tag2 #thisisareallyreallyrealyylongtag3 #notalldisabilitiesarevisible #notalldisabilitiesar #notalldisabilitiesar #notalldisabilities #tag1 #tag2 #thisisareallyreallyrealyylongtag3 #notalldisabilitiesarevisible #notalldisabilitiesar #notalldisabilitiesar #notalldisabilities #tag1 #tag2 #thisisareallyreallyrealyylongtag3 #notalldisabilitiesarevisible #notalldisabilitiesar #notalldisabilitiesar #notalldisabilities'

const textLength = 280;
const wordLength = 20;

var resu9 = str9.slice(1, textLength+1).replace(/#/g, ',');  
var truncatethen = resu9.split(',').map(str => str.slice(0, wordLength));    
truncatethen.forEach(str => console.log(str))
```